# How to change source in eclipse

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run a gradle project with lambda expressions and when I launch it I'm getting the error (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

I tried to recompile the project, restart eclipse and reinstall java

````java
AddonLoader.getOfflineAddons().removeIf(addonInfo -> addonInfo.getUuid().equals(uuid));```
````

Comment: is your compilation version set to 1.8? Go to preferences > java > compiler and check what is the version it mapped to.

Comment: @Ramesh it says that Compiler level is at 1.8

Comment: @Profi - In your javacompile part of gradle file, you can mention sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility string properties to be set to java 1.8. I think it should fix the issue.

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran thx works now

Comment: Glad to know that. Happy coding!